# Nginx File descriptor limit

Tags: nginx, file-descriptor

How can I increase the file descriptors limit in nginx?

There are several ways to increase file descriptors:

1. Edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` and set nofile soft and hard limits for the nginx user.
2. Set $ULIMIT in `/etc/default/nginx`. The nginx `init.d` script set ulimit $ULIMIT https://gist.github.com/aganov/1121022#file-nginx-L43
3. Set `worker_rlimit_nofile` in `nginx.conf` http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpMainModule#worker_rlimit_nofile

Does setting limits in `limits.conf` affect nginx when started using `init.d` script on boot?

Do I have to use ulimit $ULIMIT in the init script or can `worker_rlimit_nofile` be used instead?

When using ulimit $ULIMIT in the init script, do I still need to use `worker_rlimit_nofile` to set limits for each worker?

Thanks

Comment: Be **warned** that this may have side effects. More info [in this great answer](http://serverfault.com/a/209004/120233) on ServerFault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to increase the limit is by setting worker_rlimit_nofile.

Comment: how did you derive that?

Comment: Note to CentOS / Fedora users, if you have SELinux enabled, you will need to run `setsebool -P httpd_setrlimit 1` so that nginx has permissions to set its rlimit.

Answer (score 3):

Discussing each item:

1) /etc/security/limits.conf is only processed by pam_limits. Processes started from init.d generally do not utilize pam_limits. It's needed to set the ulimit at init level, in the service script, for example.

2) The default nginx init script doesn't have this setting (at least for Official Red Hat/CentOS packages). But changing this init script is a valid way, although it's not recommended.

3) worker_rlimit_nofile works only at process level, it's limited to the system's hard limit (ulimit -Hn). It serves to dynamically change the maximum file descriptors the nginx process can handle, which is typically defined with the system's soft limit.