# How to set nginx max open files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, limit

Though I have done the following setting, and even restarted the server:

```
# head /etc/security/limits.conf -n2
www-data soft nofile -1
www-data hard nofile -1
# /sbin/sysctl fs.file-max
fs.file-max = 201558
```

The open files limitation of specific process is still 1024/4096:

```
# ps aux | grep nginx
root       983  0.0  0.0  85872  1348 ?        Ss   15:42   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data   984  0.0  0.2  89780  6000 ?        S    15:42   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data   985  0.0  0.2  89780  5472 ?        S    15:42   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      1247  0.0  0.0  11744   916 pts/0    S+   15:47   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
# cat /proc/984/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             15845                15845                processes
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       15845                15845                signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

I've tried all possible solutions from googling but in vain. What setting did I miss?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919673/nginx-file-descriptor-limit?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**On CentOS (tested on 7.x):**

Create file `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf` with the following contents:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=65536
```

Reload systemd daemon with:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Add this to Nginx config file:

```
worker_rlimit_nofile 16384; (has to be smaller or equal to LimitNOFILE set above)
```

And finally restart Nginx:

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

You can verify that it works with `cat /proc/<nginx-pid>/limits`.

Comment: I'm confirming this is working with **Ubuntu Xenial** as well. Thanks for the approach.

Comment: maybe some day we will have a 'worker_rlimit_nofile' for the master process of the nginx: perhaps master_rlimit_nofile

Comment: From my experience, you've got to only change `worker_rlimit_nofile` and reload `nginx`. Probably unless you hit the hard limit. I was able to raise limit with `worker_rlimit_nofile` over the hard limit set for master process. Though it was under Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Additionally, on CentOS 7 you can do: `systemctl edit SERVICE_NAME`, provide the variables there, save that file and reload the service.

Comment: I try this on ubuntu20.04, if worker_rlimit_nofile  > LimitNOFILE, the max openfile is equal to worker_rlimit_nofile  value

Comment: I have set all these, and it is still not working :/

Comment: still have that 1024 there and the errors

Answer (score 13):

For nginx simply editing `nginx.conf` and setting `worker_rlimit_nofile` should change the limitation. 
I initially thought it is a self-imposed limit of nginx, but it increases limit per process:

```
worker_rlimit_nofile 4096;
```

You can test by getting a nginx process ID (from `top -u nginx`), then run:

```
cat /proc/{PID}/limits
```

To see the current limits

**Another way** on CentOS 7 is by `systemctl edit SERVICE_NAME`, add the variables there:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=65536
```

save that file and reload the service.

Answer (score 12):

I found the answer in few minutes after posting this question...

```
# cat /etc/default/nginx
# Note: You may want to look at the following page before setting the ULIMIT.
#  http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#worker_rlimit_nofile
# Set the ulimit variable if you need defaults to change.
#  Example: ULIMIT="-n 4096"
ULIMIT="-n 15000"
```

`/etc/security/limit.conf` is used by PAM, so it shoud be nothing to do with `www-data` (it's nologin user).

Comment: where is /etc/default/nginx? I only see /etc/nginx/nginx.conf , no luck setting worker_rlimit_nofile

Comment: Did you actually try your own answer? I've found nginx returns `invalid option: n` upon restarting.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for an answer for pre-systemd Debian machines, the nginx init script executes `/etc/default/nginx`. So, adding the line

```
ulimit -n 9999
```

will change the limit for the nginx daemon without messing around with the init script.

Adding `ULIMIT="-n 15000"` as in a previous answer didn't work with my nginx version.