# socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream Action cable Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, websocket, actioncable

We're working on chat app project using RubyOnRails. The app we developed working on local without any issue. However, it gives an error while trying to connect the web socket from outside. Our requirement is to use these chat app apis from an Android app.

We're using following technologies/frameworks

- Rails 5.0.0
- Ruby 2.2.2
- Action cable
- Passenger
- Nginx
- Redis

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/chatroom_demo

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;
  root /home/projects/chatroom_demo/public;

  location /cable {
       passenger_app_group_name chatroom_demo_action_cable;
       passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;

       proxy_pass http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 16384;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 20000;
    # multi_accept on;
}
```

config/cable.yml

```
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.action_cable.url = [/ws:\/\/*/, /wss:\/\/*/]
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/, /https:\/\/*/]
```

Client side we're tying to connect using following code:

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cable");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
  alert("[open] Connection established");  
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
  alert(`[error] ${error.message}`);
};
```

Client side error:  `Undefined`
Server side error:

> *32764 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX, request:
>   "GET /cable HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80/cable",
>   host: "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX"

We have tried many different ways to fix this issue but couldn't find any potential fix.

Comment: What is the result of `ulimit -Hn` and `ulimit -Sn` on your server?

Comment: @Sajad ulimit -Hn : 1048576
ulimit -Sn : 1024

Comment: try [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8949/399931) to increase limit number of open files on your system

Comment: Already tried, but no luck so far @Sajad

Comment: now this is strange :)) soft limit of 1024 on open files is quite a bit low, did you increase it for the `www-data` user too?

Answer (score 1):

Did you also update your sysd nolimitfile settings to be something > `worker_rlimit_nofile 16384`? More info [in this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849331/how-to-set-nginx-max-open-files/36423859#36423859).